# Using jquery to obtain Radio value doesn't work without using <form> declaration

Tags: java, php, jquery, html

I tried to to extract the value from a few radio buttons, but it does not work. I know there is a working answer if `<form="name of form" >` is declared however I do not wish to declare form in it as I am echoing out those radio buttons.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <input id=myForm type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
    <input id=myForm type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
    <input id=myForm type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
</body>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$('#myForm').on('change', function() {
   alert($('[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()); 
});
```

If button 1 is pressed, it gives a message `undefined variable`, but pressing button 2 and 3 gives no result.

What is wrong?

Comment: Id be unique in html

Comment: DUPLICATE IDs!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use class instead of id

```
<input class="myForm" type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
    <input class="myForm" type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
    <input class="myForm" type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
```

your jquery be

```
$('.myForm').on('change', function() {
  alert(this.value); 
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/12frhnww/)

Comment: thank you it works, ues i realise i have a duplicate ID as ID suppose to be unique

Comment: Super.. Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than duplicating id you can make use of the css class for this like

```
<body>
    <input class=myForm type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> 1 <br />
    <input class=myForm type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
    <input class=myForm type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
    </body>
```

than try jquery on it

```
   $('.myForm').on('change', function() {
      alert( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
    });
```

---

if you dont want to provide css calss than you can do below also as there is only input radio button you can aslo try

```
$( "input:radio" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
});
```

---

you can also try just name selector

```
$("input:radio[name='radioName']").on( "click", function() {
      alert( $( "input:checked" ).val() + " is checked!" );
    });
```

Comment: the alert is unnecessary complex

Comment: should be class="myform"